# understanding redox reaction

Tags: redox, oxidation-state, reduction-potential, equation-of-state

I am a total noob in chemistry, so sorry in advance if this is a very stupid question... I am trying to solve this redox reaction:

$$\ce{KClO3 + FeSO4 + H2SO4 -> Fe2(SO4)3 + KCl}$$
$$\ce{K^{+1}Cl^{+5}O^{-6}3 + Fe^{+2}S^{+6}O^{-8}_4 + H^{+2}2S^{+6}O^{-8}4 -> Fe^{+6}2(S^{+6}O^{-8}4)3 + K^{+1}Cl^{-1}}$$

When I analyze this I can see the following things:

- Fe lost some electrons, it went from +2 to +6
- Cl went from +1 to -1: a gain of elecetrons

  **But**
- I see something happened to the SO ions as well: on the left side you have two times $S^{+6}O^{-8}_4$ and on the right three times so something changed here as well. What happened? Do I have to take this into consideration as well for the calculation? And on top of that $O_3$ on the left side disappeared.

My current guess is that you never have to look at the change in oxidation state of oxygen atoms. Is that correct?

Comment: First of all, when talking about oxidation states, normally you don't multiply. You just write $\ce{Fe2^3+}$, and people will get it (correctly) as **two times** $\ce{Fe^3+}$ with a total "charge" of +6; you don't have to actually write +6 to achieve that. Also, pay attention to the formatting, especially the \ce{} thing. As for the $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ion, nothing happens to it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I thought smth did happen to $SO^{2-}_4$ as you have three of them on the right side and only two on the left side.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. Until the reaction is _balanced_, you have no idea how much of anything do you have. And once it is balanced, you'll have as much on the right as on the left.

Comment: yes you must balance the equation, meaning that there are the same number of atoms of each type on both sides . The ions present are Fe$^{2+}$, Fe$^{3+}$, ClO$_3^-$, SO$_4^{2-}$, K$^+$, Cl$^-$ and H$^+$